# How to make apache Camel a bridge between WS client and server?

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, esb

I have a webservice installed in my server1 and its wsdl is http://myServer1/MyService.wsdl(it uses Apache CXF)

and my camel esb service is installed on server2 .
I want to create a camel route .That route will only redirect request from ws client that consumes service from myserver1.

Client ---->ESB(ApacheCamel)---->http://myServer1/MyService.wsdl

so the ESB will be like a bridge.
PS:The client will generate the stub client from the myServer1 WS.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ActiveMQ to send the request from route1 to route2, and use the "replyTo" parameter , Camel will create a temporary queue that route2 will use to send the response, then route1 will go on with the response and Camel will automatically delete the temporary-queue